# Qt Application not work on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, pjsip

I am new to QT. I am facing some problem in GreenJ application.

[GreenJ](http://www.loremipsum.at/produkte/greenj/introduction/#en) is an open source Voice-over-IP phone software using pjsip and Qt.

i need to solve following issue on my app

**1)** Greenj application not work on ubuntu 13.04 (ERROR : Segmentation fault (core dumped))

**2)** how to disable security option in QtWebKit because i work with **iframe**(Error:Permission          denied to access property 'nodeType')

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first item, since you have not provided anything, at least a stack trace would be great.

About the second - the Qt security settings can be changed by setting attributes in [QWebSettings](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwebkit/qwebsettings.html) class, again, not sure what exactly is the issue, but if by mentioning iframe you meant cross URL requests then you could set `LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls`.

Comment: i already add LocalContentCanAccessRemoteUrls attribute in my Gui.cpp file but not work.i use qt4 i don't know how to add/remove specific domains to be whitelisted for cross origin requests.

Comment: A quick google search led to this - https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=117823 - seems that at least in WebKit they have recently added support for explicitly adding domains to the whitelist. Not sure if QtWebKit already exposes these API's, maybe try to build Qt 4 from latest sources? Those should include the patches.